# Why would the mud crack and fall off a ceiling repair?

Tags: repair, drywall

I closed a skylight and floated the ceiling level. A few months later it started cracking and falling,  why? I don't think it was too thick.

Comment: Is it cracking directly off the paper of the drywall? If so, I'd suspect dust interfered with the bond. Are there any signs of moisture intrusion?

Comment: Does the roof move? under wind load or snow load etc?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the damage?

Comment: I agree with aloysius dust can be a leading cause,  also mud that is dry , on pre mix work any water back in that has separated and sometimes more is needed.

Comment: Was there some grease?  (Example: one of my children played a game, dip Q-tips in vaseline, toss in the air, watch them stick to the ceiling.  I ended up with a greasy ceiling.)

Comment: What was the mud applied to?  How thick?

Answer (score 0):

Mud is pretty forgiving as regarding 'stickiness' but it won't cope with much movement, usually expansion and contraction will cause cracks.

- Could be the materials you used have dried out (framing shrinking etc.).
- Could be temperature related; i.e. expansion/contraction. Did you insulate the space over the drywall?